# How to convert an object into a double?

Tags: c#, object, graph, double

I am working on VS C# on the following code, which converts an user input
math expression and computes it.

```
        MSScriptControl.ScriptControl sc = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
        sc.Language = "VBScript";

        sc.ExecuteStatement(
            "function pi\n"
            + "pi = 3.14159265\n"
            + "end function");

        sc.ExecuteStatement(
            "function e\n"
            + "e = exp(1)\n"
            + "end function");

        expression = textBox1.Text.ToString();
        expression = expression.Replace("x", i.ToString());
        object y = sc.Eval(expression);

        string k = y.ToString();
        double result = double.Parse(k);
```

While this outputs onto the console with the correct result, I want 
to use the values to make a graph of the function user inputs and it's 
not doing it correctly.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9):

Use a cast :

```
double result = (double)y;
```

Or if it doesn't work, try `Convert.ToDouble` :

```
double result = Convert.ToDouble(y);
```